# Cqrs and rest best practice

Tags: rest, cqrs

Does anyone have best practice pattern for cqrs with put/post, specifically the client is doing a get for updated resource after it has sent command/event... Would you allow/require the client to keep local copy of the updated resource, and send a last updated timestamp in the get response? Or ensure that get includes the unprocessed commands? Of course, if the same resource is retrieved by another client, may/not get the updated resource. 
What's worked best for you? 
Would you contend with added complexity of the get also checking command queue?

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46641833/2575224

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have best practice pattern for cqrs with put/post, specifically the client is doing a get for updated resource after it has sent command/event...

How would you do it on a web site?

Normally, you would do a GET to load the resource, and that would give you version 0, possibly with some [validators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2) in the meta data to let you know what version of the representation you received.  If you tried to GET the resource again, the generic components could see from the headers that your copy was up to date, and would send you back a message to that effect ([304 Not Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1)).

When you POST to that resource, a successful response lets all of the intermediate components know that the previously cached copy of the resource has been [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4), so the next GET request will retrieve a fresh copy, with all of the modifications.

This all works great, right up to the point where, in a CQRS setting, the read requests follow a different path than the write requests.  The read side will update itself eventually, so the trick is how to avoid returning a stale representation to the client that knows it should have changed.

The analogy you are looking for is [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3); we want the write side to let the client know that the operation succeeded, and that there is a resource that can be used to get the change.

Which is to say, the write side returns a response indicating that the command was successful, and provides a link that includes data that the read model can use to determine if its copy is up to date.

The client's job is to follow the links, just like everywhere else in REST.

The link provided will of course be some safe operation, pointing to the read model.  The read model compares the information in the link to the meta data of the currently available representation; if the read model copy is up to date, it returns that, otherwise it returns a message telling the client to retry (presumably after some interval).

In short, we use polling on the read model, waiting for it to catch up.