# How to get the created object in controller when implementing CQRS

Tags: php, cqrs

I am evaluating the CQRS pattern and wonder what would be the best way to obtain an Entity created by a command in the same action so I can render it in the view.

The two options I can think of are.

1) Create an id in the controller and send it with the command to fetch the entity by finding it by id.
2) Create an instance of the entity and send it with the command so I have a reference to it after it's populated

**Example code**

```
public function createEntityAction(array $data) {
    $eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(
        CreateEntityHandler::name, // Handler
        new Entity($data) // Command
    );

    // Placeholder //
      $entity = get-the-created-entity
    // // 

    return $this->view($entity, Response::HTTP_OK);    
}
```

Comment: if you by `2)` you mean to init the `$entity` before calling `dispatch` and give to `dispatch` the `$entity` instead of `new Entity`, then yes. What speaks against that?

Comment: the whole point of CQRS is that commands and queries are separated. A command might not always even create an entity directly. It's not CRUD anymore. I guess maybe the command method could return an ID, if it created an entity. Then you can query the data store (maybe it's even a separate store or view, esp. if you do event sourcing alongside it) to get the readable data. Essentially though it's a matter of opinion, practicality and precise circumstances / requirements in your system. Also consider whether you really need CQRS, it really is only suited to certain conditions.

Comment: Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868157/in-cqrs-how-do-you-build-the-response-when-creating-an-entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second option is not really an option. "Entity creation", which is in fact is a business operation, *is* a command handling.

Generally speaking, the one who sends a command, whose handler creates an entity, should send the entity id with it. In what way the identity is generated is just an implementation concern.

Usually, command handlers either do what they suppose to do and return nothing (or ACK) or throw (or NAK).